# Mocking API Calls for Unit Tests with Mockoon and Nunit

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, mocking, nunit

I am new to Nunit and have some tests that perform API calls for a .NET 6 Web API app. I want to convert these into true unit tests by removing those external dependencies. I was looking into mocking and found [Mockoon](https://mockoon.com/).

How I would go about mocking API calls? Can I do it with Mockoon?

I wasn't sure how I could change the API calls programmatically to point to a mock API for testing only.

The ultimate goal is to automate the testing in GitHub Actions but since the tests have external dependencies, these need to be mocked first. Mockoon provides a CLI to deploy in GitHub Actions.

My project was created in VS Code so I'm not sure if Visual Studio utilities would help with configurations.

If you need any more information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/mocking-http-request-in-csharp-unit-testing-c4a7cef21828)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a broad question for SO I think. But here are some thoughts.
In my opinion, pure unit testing should mock APIs programmatically and not depend on external applications like Mockoon.

What you want to do seems to be more like integration testing, where your code is calling an external API, except that instead of maintaining an instance of the original API specifically for test/QA purposes, you maintain a mock (with Mockoon).

Then, the general idea is more or less the following:

- you prepare the mock API with Mockoon locally with the UI.
- you save Mockoon's [data file](https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/mockoon-data-files/data-storage-location/) in the repository.
- During the GitHub Actions workflow, you install Mockoon CLI and start it targeting the data file ([relevant tutorial](https://mockoon.com/tutorials/run-mock-api-anywhere-cli/)).
- You run your application tests and modify the environment variable containing the API URL to point to were the CLI is running (probably something like `http://localhost:3000`).

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by Guilaume.
I have couple things to point out for the first step:

- Don't forget that you have to press PLAY for the particular "routes" to start listening for incoming requests:
  [image]

- You have to configure the request and especially the response **Headers** or you might run into trouble
- Instead of running Github Actions I have opted to use TestContainers
- At the time of writing there is no specific Mockoon TestContainer module
- I managed to configure a GenericTestContainer to run Mockoon; it was a bit of a schlepp as I am on a Springboot/Kotlin project but it would apply to a Java project just as equally but I managed it
- I think Mockoon should have an area where bleeding edge solutions like the above can be shared on the Mockoon site (just a thought)

Comment: "I think Mockoon should have an area where bleeding edge solutions like the above can be shared on the Mockoon site"
This is what the GitHub Discussions should be for :)
https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/discussions

Comment: Âlso, I'm not familiar with TestContainers, would it be something that could/should be added to Mockoon? 
I'm open to suggestions and would be happy to discuss this with you if you have a bit of time.  You can reach me on our Discord server https://discord.com/invite/MutRpsY5gE

Comment: Well, let's put it this way, either a discussion forum (thanks for the link) or the discord will do and i will open both up to have a look. Having done the leg-work to get Springboot 2.x  TestContainer working for Mockoon, which was a natural progression for our project, I would say it should be a discussion topic yes. Why? Well, here is our journey: we used Postman for integration testing, until ISO27k01 came along, and we had to shy away from the Postman cloud storage for security reasons, we found Mockoon, and were delighted, but then we had to get it integrated for CI / IT testing.

Comment: Let's take the discussion elsewhere then, I would be happy to learn more.